# PayPal Express on product page in WooCommerce - doesn't seem to work on product page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to work out why the **PayPal Express Checkout**  doesn't work on my page. I have had to disable it for the moment (as it's a live site), but you can see the page here:

https://steampunkjunkies.com/product/cryptex-original-black-32gb-usb-drive/

Here is what I ticked in the settings for **WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout > PayPal Express Checkout**:

[image]

And this is how it looks on the product page:

[image]

The plugin I'm using is **WooCommerce PayPal Express Checkout Gateway**

The big issue is:

1. When you press it with nothing in your cart, it just says your cart is empty
2. If you have items in your cart already, it will send you to PayPal correctly, but it doesn't add the item in question

Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Same issue found on another website also.

Comment: @MansoorkhanCherupuzha ah ok, so sounds like an issue with the plugin itself? I struggled to find an official demo with it, so I could try it out on a standard theme etc

Comment: This issue can be solved by an alternative free plugin -https://wordpress.org/plugins/express-checkout/ This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by an alternative free plugin -
https://wordpress.org/plugins/express-checkout

This worked for me.